# Configure APNS with eJabberD server?

Tags: apple-push-notifications, xmpp, ejabberd

I have eJabberD setup and it successfully set-up to delivered message on mobile device. To delivered message in case if mobile device is offline(for iOS)I'm trying to configure APNS with eJabberD.

On client side I'm already passing ***Device_Token*** and ***Apple_Push*** Tag in ***iq>*** stanzas, mentioned [here](https://ejabberd-saas.com/Mobile_XMPP_Stack.pdf). But that is not working. But I'm not sure what are configuration I have to done at Server side to make it work. Any suggestion !!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [mod_push](https://github.com/royneary/mod_push).
Check if it's listed when with 'ejabberdctl modules_available'. If so, 'ejabberd module_install mod_push'. Otherwise, follow the installation directions on the mod_push github, adjusting as necessary for your configuration.

Configuration directions are available on the github page.